# iOS Simulator with iOS11 (Xcode 9) device missing from desktop Safari's Develop menu

Tags: ios, xcode, safari, web-inspector

I'm trying to debug simulated devices in Xcode's Simulator using desktop Safari's Web Inspector.

A simulated device (iPad Air 2) does **not** appear in Safari's `Develop` menu when its Simulator is running. (The `Simulator` menu item doesn't even appear at all.)

- iOS in simulated device has `Settings > Safari > Develop > Web Inspector` enabled
- OS and all apps are most current version (App Store confirms "No Updates Available")

Is there any way to actually get this to work?

[image: image showing all apps and versions]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry if this is a bit late, but for the new version of xcode you need safari technology preview (https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/), and use that instead of regular safari to debug xcode simulator

Comment: This was true at the time this was posted. As of today it is working correctly without the need for Safari Technology Preview. Normal Safari 12 and Xcode/Simulator 10.1.

Answer (score 1):

**You may need to make sure that Xcode command line tools was installed and configured properly:**

1. If not installed, you can install it via Terminal by running this command `xcode-select --install`.
2. Then verify installation by printing the version with this command `xcode-select -version`.
3. Print Xcode path with this command `xcode-select -print-path`.
4. If path is incorrect, switch to the correct one by this command `sudo xcode-select -switch "your Xcode path, usually it is /Applications/Xcode.app/ "`, provide your password if required by Terminal.

After above steps, quit simulator and Safari, then restart them. The simulator should appear in the Develop menu of Safari.

Worked on macOS Catalina 10.15.4, Xcode 11.4, and Safari 13.1.